# How to compute limits involving fractional part?

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x\to0^{+}} x(\{\frac{1}{x}\}+\{\frac{2}{x}\}+\cdots+\{\frac{15}{x}\})$, where {.} represents fractional part.

Here is my thought process

$0\le\{\frac{n}{x}\}\lt1 \implies \lim_{x\to0^{+}}0\le\lim_{x\to0^{+}}x\{\frac{n}{x}\}\lt\lim_{x\to0^{+}}x  \implies \lim_{x\to0^{+}}x\{\frac{n}{x}\} = 0$

is this correct? any help is appreciated.

Comment: The curly brackets represents the fractional part, is it? E.g. $\{2.5\} = 0.5$.

Comment: What if $x=\dfrac1{10^n}$

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг , yes it represents fractional part.

Comment: Thanks @labbhattacharjee, I get it now !

Comment: Then the answer below is correct, it is just the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг , yes it is, but I can't accept any answer for 4 mins.

Comment: @John You are right, you can accept it after that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fractional part is always bounded between $1$ and $0$, thus for $x>0$

$$ 0 < x\left(\left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\} + \cdots + \left\{\frac{15}{x}\right\}\right) < 15x \implies \lim_{x\to 0^+}x\left(\left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\} + \cdots + \left\{\frac{15}{x}\right\}\right) = 0$$

by squeeze theorem.